# SVN ignore .pdf is not working

Tags: svn

Trying to ignore .pdf from svn check-in. But it's not working.

Code: `svn propset svn:ignore '*.pdf'` .
Then committed the changes.

Still able to check-in .pdf file in svn ? Any help?

Comment: Ignore does not prevent you from adding a file, it just should ignore it unless you specifically add it.

Comment: Thanks crashmstr...Is there a way that I can accomplish this without using commit hooks?

Comment: If you want to *block* the check-in of PDF files, you need to add a pre-commit hook. But if they are ignored property, there should be less likely for a developer to add one by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This code will only work on the "current" directory. You must set it recursively, using -R

Comment: This code is not working for the current directory also. I tried -R too

Comment: Ok, so try `svn propset svn:ignore *.pdf`

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid the check in even if specifically added. At the moment, it looks like commit hooks are the way to go. I would like to know if there are other approaches as well. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've found this website. Check whether the solution works or not :) http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html